# Can one translate any sequence into a set of ordered tuples?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

There are two kinds of sequences:

1. a1, a2,...,an (finite)
2. a1, a2,... (infinite)

Sequence 1) can be described by an ordered n-tuple, i.e. the set of the sequence *itself* has an ordered structure. For instance "1,2,3" = {((1,2),3)} and you could even go fruther and notate it in pure set notation.

Is that also possible with sequences for type 2), e.g. by some kind of recursion or induction, so that at the end you get a set of infinitely many tuples? I mean there is certainly a pattern one could use because

1,2 = (1,2)

1,2,3 = ((1,2),3)

1,2,3,4 = (((1,2),3),4)

...

As I understand it now, sequences of type 2 are defined as functions, but those sets of functions lose their order. For instance: 1,2,3... = f = {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)...} but in f itself there would be no order, so you could also write f = {(3,3),(1,1),(2,2)}. That is bad. I would want order in the very set that underlies the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method is to use ordered pairs to define functions, and then define finite and infinite sequences in terms of functions.

Once we have a definition of ordered pair, the *only* thing we use about that definition is its "defining property":
$$(a,b)=(c,d)\iff a=c\text{ and }b=d.$$

Having defined "ordered pair", we define "cartesian product of two sets": given sets $A$ and $B$, $A\times B$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. (Here we do want to use the precise definition of ordered pair, in order to guarantee that this is a set whenever $A$ and $B$ are sets; but this is a technical issue and easily disposed of).

And once we have cartesian products of two sets, we can define functions:

> **Definition.** Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. A function from $A$ to $B$ is a subset $f\subseteq A\times B$ with the following two properties:
>
> 1. For all $a\in A$ there exists $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$; and
> 2. For all $a\in A$ and $b,b'\in B$, if $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,b')\in f$, then $b=b'$.

We then write "$f\colon A\to B$" as shorthand for "$f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$", and write "$f(a)=b$" as shorthand for "$a\in A$, $b\in B$, and $(a,b)\in f$.

And now we can easily define finite sequences: recall that we define the natural numbers by letting $0=\varnothing$, and letting $n+1=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$. We then define an "ordered $n$-tuple" of elements of $A$ to be a function $f\colon n\to A$; we write $(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1})$ to mean $f(0)=a_0$, $f(1)=a_1$, etc.  So the sequence $1$, $2$, $3$ means a function $f\colon 3\to\{1,2,3\}$ with $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=2$, and $f(2)=3$; that is, the set $\{(0,1), (1,2), (2,3)\}$. The sequence $3,1,2$ corresponds to the function $\{(0,3), (1,1), (2,2)\}$. Etc.

Infinite sequences of elements of $A$ are formally defined as functions with domain $\mathbb{N}$, $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to A$, in the same manner.

---

One *can* generalize the definition of ordered pair to one of ordered triple; you can say that the ordered triple $(a,b,c)$ is the set $\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\},\{\{ \{a\},\{a,b\}\},c\}\}$; that is, the ordered pair $((a,b),c)$, and continue that way. Or other variants. It works, but is more cumbersome than switching to "functions with domain a natural number".

Comment: Ok, I come to a different formlization as a set, could u check if yours or mine is correct? (a, b, c) = ((a, b), c) = {{{{a},{a, b}}}, {{{a},{a, b}}, c}}.

Comment: @Pippen: I may be missing a pair of curly brackets. It's hard to parse... which is why people don't usually do it so explicitly.

Comment: So can I say: we can not only order every n-Tupel with Kuratowski's defintion of ordered pairs eventually, but we can also order every n*-Tupel where n* stands for an infinite sequence with Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs eventually?

Comment: @Pippen First: "tuple". Second, it is unclear what you mean by "order with Kuratowski's definition"; or what "eventually" means. We can bootstrap **any** definition of ordered pair into a definition of "ordered $n$-tuple" (or even "ordered $I$-tuple" for any totally ordered set $I$), not just Kuratowski's. But it would be hard to use the second version (where an ordered triple is an ordered pair of an ordered pair and an element, etc) to get all the way to $\omega$.

Comment: I mean it like this: We can write the sequence 1,2,3,...,n as an set of ordered pairs eventually, right? But what about the sequence 1,2,3,... that goes on into infinity? Can we also write that sequence as an set of ordered pairs (of course only in theory, nobody could actually do it)?

Comment: @Pippen: Again, what does "eventually" mean? If you write it as a function, then there is no "eventually". If you want to write it as a pair, whose first entry is a pair, whose first entry is a pair... etc., then this does **not** generalize to infinite sequences. Which is why it is not the usual way of  doing it.

Comment: @Pippen: Let me note that accepting an answer is a signal that you are satisfied with the answer. It discourages other people from writing their own answers. If you were not satisfied, as seems to be the case, then you should **not** accept it yet.